# Replace a certain number of characters with * in the middle of the line

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I want change email **example@gmail.com** to **ex*****@gmail.com** to get the same amount of `*` as much as symbols was replaced.

How I should change this code?

```
preg_replace("/([_a-zA-Z0-9-]{2})([-a-z0-9]*)(@[_a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/i", "$1****$3", $model->email);
```

Comment: IYou have to use regex or another method?

Comment: Лёня, if any of the answers works please consider accepting (there is a grey tick to the left of the answer for you to click).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `preg_replace_callback`:

```
$s = "example@gmail.com";
$s = preg_replace_callback(
    "/([\w-]{2})([-a-z0-9]*)(@[\w-]+)/i", 
    function ($m) { return $m[1] . str_repeat("*", strlen($m[2])). $m[3]; }, 
    $s);
echo $s; // => ex*****@gmail.com
```

See the [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/wBfqs5).

Details:

- `[_a-zA-Z0-9]`  can be replaced with `\w`
- `function($m) {...}` is a callback function where you may manipulate the match data
- `str_repeat("*", strlen($m[2]))` just builds a string of `*` chars the same amount of times as the Group 2 length.

**NOTE**

If you must do it with `preg_replace`, you may use

```
preg_replace('~(?:\G(?!^)|[\w-]{2}(?=[\w-]*@))\K[^@]~', '*', $s)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/aZQghB/3)

**Details**

- `(?:\G(?!^)|[\w-]{2})` - either the end of the previous successful match (`\G(?!^)`) or (`|`) 2 word or `-` chars (`[\w-]{2}`) that are followed with zero or more chars other than word and `-` chars and a `@`  (see `(?=[\w-]*@)`)
- `\K` - omit what we matched
- `[^@]` - any char other than `@`.

Comment: I was going to post this :D (y)

Comment: @hassan However, there is another pure regex approach, see my update :)

Comment: Yes, @bobblebubble, perhaps, it makes sense in this situation. It will only be checked once.

Answer (score 0):

`example.gmail.com` - is not an email.

Your regex will work fine with search string like `example@gmail.com`

If you want to work with strings like `example.gmail.com` - you must change your expression to:

```
preg_replace("/([_a-zA-Z0-9-]{2})([-a-z0-9]*)(.[_a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/i", "$1****$3", $model->email);
```

[DEMO](http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/l75) (Switch to `preg_replace` tab)

[**UPDATE**] Question was edited. First given example string was `example.gmail.com`

Answer (score 0):

Your regular expression matches `@` symbol which is not available in your given example string. change it with `.|@` This will match either `.` or `@`

```
$email = "example.gmail.com";
$new_email  = preg_replace("/([_a-zA-Z0-9-]{2})([-a-z0-9]*)((.|@)[_a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/i", "$1****$3", $email);
echo $new_email;
```

[DEMO](https://3v4l.org/nBHVA)